# Explicit correspondences in cohomology

Tags: homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, class-field-theory

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}} \newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}$
In class field theory, one typically identifies many groups such as
$$\begin{align*}
&H^{-2}(G, \Z) \cong H_1(G, \Z) \cong H_0(G,I_G) \cong I_G/I_G^2 \cong G^{ab}\\
&H^1(G, \Q/\Z) \cong \text{Hom}(G, \Q/\Z)\\
&H^{-1}(G, \Q/\Z) \cong \frac{1}{n}\Z/\Z \text{ where } n = |G|
\end{align*}$$
(All cohomology groups are Tate cohomology. $I_G$ is the augmentation ideal.)

My problem is how does one know how to manipulate them. For instance, the cup product
$$H^{-2}(G, \Z) \otimes H^1(H, \Q/\Z) \rightarrow H^{-1}(G, \Q/\Z)$$
naturally induces
$$G^{ab} \otimes \text{Hom}(G, \Q/\Z) \rightarrow \frac{1}{n}\Z/\Z$$
via the above identification.

The most reasonable/natural expectation of the latter map should be to send
$$s, \chi \mapsto \chi(s)$$
and I know this is true by establishing all inverses
$$\begin{align*}
G^{ab} &\rightarrow H^{-2}(G, \Z)\\
\text{Hom}(G, \Q/\Z) &\rightarrow  H^1(G, \Q/\Z)
\end{align*}$$
in term of the cochain complex for Tate cohomology and makes use of the explicit definition of cup product in Cassels and Frohlich. [I might get the first map wrong. Tracing the chain of isomorphism backward, it should be
$$\begin{align*}
g \in G^{ab} &\mapsto \text{class of } g - 1  \text{ in } I_G/I_G^2\\
&\mapsto \text{class of } 1 \otimes (g - 1) \in \Z[G] \otimes_G I_G \text{ in } H_0(G, I_G)\\
&\mapsto \text{class of } (g, 1) \otimes 1 \in \Z[G^2] \otimes_G \Z \text{ in } H_1(G, \Z) \\
& \qquad \text{ via explicit computation of the connecting hom}\\
&\mapsto \text{class of } \Z[G^2]^* \rightarrow \Z; f \mapsto f(g,1) \text{ in } H^{-2}(G, \Z)
\end{align*}$$
while the second one is much easier
$$\chi \in \text{Hom}(G, \Q/\Z) \mapsto [\text{class of cochain } \Z[G^2] \rightarrow \Q/\Z : (g_0, g_1) \mapsto \chi(g_0^{-1} g_1)].$$
If possible, please help me check these as well. Some instances of 1 are integers while other should be the identity $1_G$ of $G$.]

I have seen other instances such as
$$\chi(\phi_{L/K}(\alpha)) = \text{inv}_K(\alpha \cup \delta\chi)$$
(Cassels and Frohlich, page 140, Prop. 1) but the given proof in no way illustrates how one knows all those correspondences. For instance, it is stated that

> Moreover, the identification between $H^{-2}(G, \Z)$ and $G^{ab}$ has been so made in order to ensure that $s \cup \chi = \chi(s)$.

So my questions are:

- How does one make sense of what to do when dealing with these implicit identification between cohomology groups? In particular, is there a way to know that the induced map $G^{ab} \otimes \text{Hom}(G, \Q/\Z) \rightarrow \frac{1}{n}\Z/\Z$ that I mentioned above must be $s \cup \chi = \chi(s)$ without doing all those explicit computation?
- Is there an intuitive explanation of the cup product? In particular, how does one expect to prove 2-periodicity using cup product in the first place; given its complexity?